# Calcular 1% de un sueldo por cada mes trabajado python, extraccion de meses en formato fecha

Tags: python

Tengo que calcular el 1% del sueldo por cada mes trabajado, para eso yo trate de hacer esto

```
def convFecha(fechaIngreso):
    global fecha_dt
    fecha_dt = datetime.strptime(fechaIngreso, '%d/%m/%Y')
    print(fecha_dt)
    print(type(fecha_dt))
    fechaIngresEmpleados.append(fecha_dt)

convFecha(fechaIngreso)
```

el codigo de arriba es para convertir el string del input a formato fecha y luego insertarlo en una lista

```
def difFecha(fecha_dt):
    diferencia = datetime.now() - fecha_dt
    print(diferencia * 1/ 30)

difFecha(fecha_dt)
```

este codigo es para sacar la diferencia entre la fecha actual y la fecha ingresada, el output me da un resultado en dias y lo dividi entre 30, sin embargo no todos los meses tienen 30 dias, algunos 31, otros 28 y 29 y no se podra saber con exactitud cuantos meses pasaron
alguna recomendacion para extraer el mes de un formato fecha o alguna otra alternativa?

Comment: Invoco el poder de Google y obtengo [Best way to find the months between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039879/best-way-to-find-the-months-between-two-dates#4040338)

Comment: Entre el 15 de Enero y el 15 de Febrero, ¿cuantos meses son? Entre el 31 de Enero y el 1 de Marzo, ¿cuantos meses?